# How to refresh the textblock in real-time in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a host computer software based on serialport communication, and I get a problem about receiving the serial data.

Now I am receiving and displaying the data like this:

XAML：

```xml
<ScrollViewer>
    <TextBlock Name="SerialRecvInfoTextBlock"
               Text="{Binding Path=SerialRecvInfo, Mode=OneWay}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

C#：

```cs
public void AddText(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort _port = (SerialPort)sender;
    // get the serial data

    byte[] recvData = new byte[_port.BytesToRead];
    _port.Read(recvData, 0, _port.BytesToRead);
    string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recvData);
    SerialRecvInfo += DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " " + str + "\r\n";
}
```

The function `AddText` is  added to the `IO.Ports.DataReceived`，and can get the data in anther thread.

---

My problem is that when i received the data from serialport, the textblock cannot refresh the data in real-time, almost delay for 1 - 2 seconds.

The more data I have send, the longer delay I got. I have test the exec time of `AddText`, but it takes a short time (less than 1ms). So I am thinking about the performance of textblock, or there's a problem about the databinding( such as the propertychanged invoker? )

Comment: OK so characters are coming in on the serial port.  How fast are they coming in?  How many updates per second?  And how fast would a user need to see updates?

Comment: @Joe Thanks for your comment. The baudrate is 256000, and I am using virtual serialport to test it. The rate is about 500-1000bytes per 100ms.
I hope that the delay can be reduced to less than 100ms.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question.  How much frequency does a user actually need on a visual control?  How many times per second would a user need to see an update?   Suppose the text changes 100 times per second?  How useful would it be for a user to see those updates?  What human could possibly make any sense of that?

Comment: @Joe I know it, the refresh rate is not a serious problem in a host controller, the app can be working well.
 I just want to know why I get a big delay in my code. I have test it using other serialport assitant, they have a quick response for the data receiving.

Comment: And what thread is this port receiving on?    The typical model with serial communications is receiving in the background.  I would certainly want that in a design.  If your port is receiving data on the UI thread that's going to lock everything up.

Comment: Everytime you receive a character from the serial port, you are triggering an update for the Textblock. So that are about 5000 -10.000 updates per second  which is way to high: you are flooding the UI with rendering requests it may not be able to keep up with and that may cause delays.
Furthermore the way you append a string to `SerialRecvInfo` at the same rate is very  inefficient (massive number of memory allocations for ever larger versions of the string, propably causing a lot of garbage collections) which on its own may lead to slow program execution (and delays).

Comment: A better solution might be to add the strings for the received data in a `List<string>` (instead of concatenating them to a single string. And then refreshing a `ListView` from that List e.g. every 100msec (based on a timer).
In that way you limit the number of string allocations and re-renderings of your UI to a reasonable level.
By the way: creating the individual stings using a `ListBuilder` would be even better.

Comment: Where is `SerialRecvInfo` declared? In the xaml.cs? Is it a DependencyProperty? In WPF a property gets updated by the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface when using a ViewModel (see: MVVM), or via DependecyProperties. Direct setting the Value is not really predictable when to show up - if even.... You also could try to `Dispatcher.Invoke(...)`

Comment: This will produce enormous ammounts of garbage since you create new strings which get longer and longer.
Better use a listbox and display the latest 1000 lines or so.

Efecctively, your soloution will eventually run out of memory and consume 99% CPU time since the GarbageCollector (GC) is overwhelmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `INotifyPropertyChanged` to your class and fire the event in the setter of your property, just like in the example below.

```cs
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private string _serialRecvInfo;
private string SerialRecvInfo
{
    get => _serialRecvInfo;
    set
    {
        _serialRecvInfo = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SerialRecvInfo)));
    }
}
```